# Decompressing .bz2 stream to file in C#

Tags: c#, sharpziplib, bzip2

I'm having real trouble trying to use the .bz2 stuff from the SharpZipLib library and I've not been able to find any help else where.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated and if anyone can point me at an existing solution I can learn from that would be fantastic!

Below is what I'm trying to do, but obviously it's not working. Currently the problem I'm having is an 'EndOfStreamException' being unhandled on the marked line. The code is a bit of a mess, I've never tried to do anything like this before...

As you can probably tell I'm downloading this from the web before decompressing it, I'm fairly sure that part of the code works correctly though.

```
while ((inputByte = responseStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(ms))
        {
            writer.Write((byte)inputByte);
        }

        using (BZip2InputStream unzip = new BZip2InputStream(ms)) //Exception occurs here
        {
            buffer = new byte[unzip.Length];
            unzip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `using` statements.  `using` statements are compiler directives for a `try finally` to be wrapped around the block of code and `IDisposible.Dispose()` will be called when the `finally` is executed.

Long story short, calling dispose on the `BinaryWriter`, `BZip2InputStream`, and `FileStream` are probably prematurely disposing of the parent `MemoryStream`.

Try removing the three `using` blocks from within the `MemoryStream` and see if that fixes your issue.

**Edit**

Your `BinaryWriter` is writing a single `byte` to the `MemoryStream`.  I don't believe you need a `BinaryWriter` for this as `MemoryStream` has a `WriteByte()` method.

Then your `BZip2InputStream` is trying to read from the `MemoryStream`.  But the `MemoryStream` has it's position at the end of the stream.  There is no data to read, hence the `EndOfStreamException`.

Comment: Just tried this and unfortunately that doesn't seem to actually solve the issue, but something I hadn't even considered all the same. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You are still receiving the `EndOfStreamException`?  What line is doing it?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's exactly the same line as before when creating the BZip2InputStream

Comment: I believe the last time I looked at SharpZipLib it was no longer being supported.  And IIRC it had really bad performance either packing or unpacking.  The most popular free .NET zip library I've seen was [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).  I am not sure if that is an option, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: Oh wow, yeah I saw what you mean now...
Fantastic help, thanks a lot! All working now!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the OP's code. **First one**, as Jason Whitted mentioned, is that the `using` code block of the `BinaryWriter` causes disposal of the `MemoryStream` instance, so we should remove the block and because `MemoryStream` itself has a `write` method, this can be achieved in the most clean way using the following:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(inputBytes,0,inputBytes.Length);
```

**The second problem** is that when we write to the `MemoryStream` instance (ms), we go to the end of it, so before we try using `BZip2InputStream` we must change the position back to the beginning of the memory stream:

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //THIS IS NECESSARY to change the position to the beginning
byte[] buffer = null;
using (var bz2InputStream = new BZip2InputStream(ms))
{
       buffer = new byte[bz2InputStream.Length];
       bz2InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```